# Missing some posts from Instagram Legacy APIs "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent"

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am not getting some posts or some posts are missing while I am trying to get posts from this API. Also, I tried to report this bug on Instagram but they are no longer accepting bug reports.
[image: Instagram Platform message while trying to report a bug]

Is there is any way or do I have to switch to Instagram Graph? My customers are getting frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue with legacy Instagram API. Some posts are simply not present in response from the legacy API. In my case majority of the cases were connected to Instagram Business accounts. Switching to Instagram Graph API/Basic Display API solves the problem.

You can also double check if the missing posts are not IGTV posts. They are not returned from the API (even from the Instagram Graph API and Basic Display API).

I would recommend switching to new API anyway, since the legacy API will be turned off on June 29th, 2020 (https://www.instagram.com/developer/).